# Using XOR function to XoR words together from a character bits

Tags: javascript, encryption, hash, binary, xor

I'm currently working on a hashing algorithm in school and I'm getting information from a tutorial online.

https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/guides/how-does-a-hashing-algorithm-work/

In the tutorial on step 9 they want me to XoR words together and create 80 words from my character bit words. I don't exactly know how to do it but I get the idea.

My current 16x32 character bit words look like this (The same as in the tutorial):

```
01000011010100100101100101010000 
010101000100111110­0­0­0­0­0­0­0­0­0­0­0000    
00000000000000000000000000000000 
00000000000000000000000000000000    
00000000000000000000000000000000 
00000000000000000000000000000000    
00000000000000000000000000000000 
00000000000000000000000000000000    
00000000000000000000000000000000 
00000000000000000000000000000000    
00000000000000000000000000000000 
00000000000000000000000000000000    
00000000000000000000000000000000 
00000000000000000000000000000000    
00000000000000000000000000000000 
00000000000000000000000000110000
```

And this is what the tutorial wants me to do.

> Transform the 16 x 32 character bit words into 80 words using a step
>   loop function. First select four words for the first run through the
>   loop which are strings 1,3,9 &14 from step 8.
>
> The next time through the loop we will use words 2,4,10,15 from stage
>   8.
>
> The next process is to XoR the words together. Xoring is just a basic
>   computational function that gives the output of q only if the two
>   inputs both have a 1 in that position – if they don’t the output is
>   zero.

```
The function is ((14 XOR 9) XOR 3) XOR 1) which is:

00000000000000000000000000000000
XOR
01000011010100100101100101010000
Is
01000011010100100101100101010000
```

This is my code:

```
function convertToROA(n) {
    var h1 = "01100111010001010010001100000001";
    var h2 = "11101111110011011010101110001001";
    var h3 = "10011000101110101101110011111110";
    var h4 = "00010000001100100101010001110110";
    var h5 = "11000011110100101110000111110000";


    var intBit = "";

    var binary = "";

    n.forEach(function(element) {
      binary = binary + 0 + (element).toString(2);
    });

    var length = binary.length;

    intBit = intBit + binary + 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < (2**9)-length-1; i++) {
      intBit = intBit + "0";
    }

    console.log(intBit.length);
    console.log(binary);
    console.log(binary.length);
    console.log((binary.length).toString(2).length);

    intBit = intBit.substring(0, (2**9)-((binary.length).toString(2).length));
    intBit = intBit + (binary.length).toString(2);

    console.log(intBit);

    var splitText = intBit.match(/.{32}|/g);

    console.log(splitText);
}
```

Comment: I have made it so i have the binary codes all inserted into the 16x32 character bit words. All i want is to understan what he means on step 10 :)